# Will java CRC32 result overflow 32bit?

Tags: java, c++, crc32

I am using boost crc32 to simluate java version:

```
long HashUtils::CalcCRC32(const std::wstring& filePath)
    {
        HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(filePath.c_str(), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
        if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            return 0;
        std::vector<byte> buff;
        DWORD dwSize = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);
        buff.resize(dwSize);
        boost::crc_32_type crc32;
        DWORD bytesRead = 0;
        if (!ReadFile(hFile, buff.data(), buff.size(), &bytesRead, 0) || bytesRead != dwSize) {
            CloseHandle(hFile);
            return 0;
        }
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        crc32.process_block(buff.data(), buff.data() + buff.size());
        return crc32.checksum();
    }
```

The java version

```
private static long calcCRC32(byte[] raw, int offset, int len) throws IOException {
        CRC32 crc32 = new CRC32();
        crc32.update(raw, offset, len);
        return crc32.getValue();
    }
```

The problem is java version return long, which is 64bit, while the c++/boost version return long which is 32bit. Will the crc32 result of the java version overflow 32bit?

Comment: Java returning long stems from implementing the interface java.util.zip.Checksum. In general java is hardened enough, that you may rely on having only 32 variable bits. _(Please check the sources if you write for a nuclear power plant.)_

Comment: Have you tried to use a int64_t?

Comment: @Schoentoon: What would be the point of that? The CRC32 algorithm produces 32 bits of output.

Comment: @MSalters I quote "The problem is java version return long, which is 64bit."

Comment: So? The CRC32 algorithm still produces 32 bits of output. That leaves the other 32 bits zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The java CRC32 class only returns 32 bit CRCs. Therefore the int datatype is large enough to hold all the information. You can rewrite your function as this:

```
private static int calcCRC32(byte[] raw, int offset, int len) throws IOException
{
      CRC32 crc32 = new CRC32();
      crc32.update(raw, offset, len);
      return (int)crc32.getValue();
}
```

Now you should have similar results from the C++ and java version.

The reason that crc.getValue() returns a long instead of an int is quite simple by the way: CRC32 implements the Checksum interface. This interface has been specified to return long for the getValue() method. This was done to allow for checksum implementations that return more than 32 useful bits of information.

Comment: The other reason to return a long for a 32-bit CRC is so that you can get a non-negative value.  A CRC is considered to be an unsigned integer, for which a 32-bit unsigned cannot be represented in a Java int.  Yes, you can store all 32-bits in an int, but I have seen many questions on SO about why my 32-bit CRC is wrong, referring to the fact that they are trying to compare a positive version with a negative version.  E.g. 2477112321 with -1817854975.  They don't match!  But they're actually the same 32-bit value.